# What is extension_access_modifier swiftlint?

Tags: ios, swift, access-modifiers, swift-extensions, swiftlint

I added Swiftlint to a project and I'm having trouble understanding what the warning is for `extension_access_modifier`.  I see it mainly on a class that is declared as public, but there are extensions littered throughout the codebase that adds functionality.

```
public class Foo {

}

// In SomeOtherClass.swift
extension Foo { // Extension Access Modifier Violation: Prefer to use extension access modifiers
    public func baz()
}
```

Whenever there is `extension Foo` in another class, I get that warning on the extension.  Would someone explain what it is?

Comment: it probably prefers the `extension` be `public`, rather than the `func`

Comment: @Alexander When I add public to the extension (e.g. `public extension foo`), the warning then appears on the `public func baz()` method

Comment: if the `extension` is explicitly `public`, the `func` doesn't need too be

Comment: @Alexander can you put your comment in the answer. that worked. public extension without the public on the baz() function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's clearer to express that your extension is public, rather than all its members:

Prefer:

```
public extension Foo {
    func bar() { ... }
    func baz() { ... }
    func qux() { ... }
}
```

over

```
extension Foo {
    public func bar() { ... }
    public func baz() { ... }
    public func qux() { ... }
}
```

Comment: lol. My project has the exact opposite. I guess it's there to avoid spamming the user of your library with your extensions i.e. I'm getting: 'No Extension Access Modifier Violation: Prefer **not** to use extension access modifiers (no_extension_access_modifier)'

Comment: @Honey Both variants I show end up `spamming the user of your library with your extensions`. `bar`, `baz` and `qux` are still public in both variants.

Comment: True. I was just pointing out the my swiftlint will pop a warning if you do `public extension Foo`. I landed at this page when I was searching for the error _I_ got. It's similar to the error in the question, but yet totally the opposite

Comment: Except that it complains even if you have only one function. Not sure that is helpful: ```extension AppDelegate {
    public func initXxxxx() {} ``` Because any latter functions you add, you might not want those to be public. Or they might end up public by mistake.